# Hold and let's go!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Abel, Dennis & Jack, *play*ful as they are, came up with a puzzle.

---

I choose a common drink instead of the first vitamin. (6)

I choose the sound of a pirate instead of energy and adds an alien at the end. (6)

I choose a common drink which takes the lead and make a small change to make it masculine at the end. (5)

### What are we?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each of the three players is responsible for one line of the puzzle. Their intention is for you to:

> follow the clues to manipulate certain letters in their own names to make other words.

*I choose a common drink instead of the first vitamin. (6)*

> This is **Dennis**'s line. If we replace 'D' (the first letter of his name which is also a vitamin) with 'T' (a soundalike of 'tea', a common drink) we get **TENNIS**.

*I choose the sound of a pirate instead of energy and adds an alien at the end. (6)*

> This is **Jack**'s line. If we replace his 'J' (for Joule, the unit of energy) with 'R' (as in 'AAAARRR!' - a pirate's cry), and add 'ET' (an alien, i.e. Extra-Terrestrial) to the end, JACK becomes **RACKET**.

*I choose a common drink which takes the lead and make a small change to make it masculine at the end. (5)*

> This is **Abel**'s line. If we add a 'T' ('tea') to the front and switch the last two letters to make 'le', the French masculine pronoun (although, notably, 'el' is itself the Spanish masculine pronoun), ABEL becomes **TABLE**.

If we then list these words in the same order as their names were originally presented...

> 'Abel Dennis Jack' becomes **TABLE TENNIS RACKET**, which is something that - as per the title - you can *hold* and then use to play a game ("let's go!").

Comment: Correct and well done!

Comment: How does this guy solve these puzzles so fast? :)